# What are the odds that this site will be canonized if this goes on...?

Tags: discussion

I've got a bit of time, effort and interest invested in this SE project.

If you wrangle the numbers on StackExchange.com, Christianity.SE seems to be ahead of the curve of recently started sites, except for maybe the bitcoin and possibly economics.

This site needs a big boost in viewership and a marginal boost in questionership.

So, in the interest of being interesting, can we come up with a way to boost these (in a non-temporary way)?

Comment: Do we want to promote the site before we finish determining what it is?

Comment: I think so, that may be the only way to discover what this site is.  In any event, we won't be promoting asking questions, only the answers given. Also, I've got a pretty clear conception about what the site is, I'm batting about .98 on my closed question percentage.  That's a lot better than I was doing on [programmers.SE]!

Comment: @JustinY: Don't wait until the site is "perfect" to start actively promoting it... because that activity is never be finished. Most of these back-room issue you wrangle with don't really impact the experience of the front-end user who is just here to enjoy the site. Believe it or not, you are already well-beyond those early *formative* stages of most sites... and, besides, there's nothing wrong with involving a much larger audience in those formative stages. It is very engaging. Don't wait.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't ask this question without having an idea how to answer it so here goes.

Spamming is obviously unethical and I don't think anyone at SE.Inc wants to get links back to stackexchange stuck on blacklists.

But, here is my idea. If you read a person's Christianity related blog and have a question (or disagreement) with what they're saying. Do two things:

1. Ask here for clarification (post a link to the blog in question), wait for the answer.
2. Ask them for clarification (in their blog's comments), post a link to the answer you got on Christianity.SE.

Now that's what I call killing two birds in one bush with two stones.

SEO is fun!

Answer (score 3):

To add to [@Peter](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/765/69)'s answer, I promote the site via Twitter and Google+ primarily by posting links to interesting questions (all of mine, and many others as I go).

I do the same thing with all the other SE sites I participate in - and other websites I come across that are interesting to me.

I also promote relevant sites via direct links and "suggestions" to friends, colleagues, and fellow church members (in the specific context of Christianity.SE).

If all of the "active" users did similar things, I bet the site would grow pretty organically, and shouldn't burst its seams.